# DomPDF does not work with div tables?

Tags: php, pdf, responsive-design, export, dompdf

I am developing a module on a website to export some reports to pdf. After searching on google which kind of library could help me I found DOMPDF (php).

I am creating and showing correctly the pdf but I have to create the html with tables, tr and td because when I try to display the same using divs with display option set on table, table-row or table-cell it does not work and do not show the data in a correct tabulated format.

This is a problem because in the views I try to use divs and responsiv design, but when I pass as a parameter this html it does not work. By this fact while I am testing this I had to create a view with both html codes. The first for the view render with the div design and another with tables tags that is passed as a parameter to the dompdf render.

Could any one if is a programming problem, dompdf problem or anything else?

Any suggestion is welcomen.

Here the code

```
                <link href="pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   media="screen" />
                <div class="tabledivinscripcion">
                <div class="titular-inscripcion">
                        <img id="header" class="headers" src="ImagenesNoticias/'.$row_headers["timestamp"].'_'.$row_headers["header"].'"/>
                </div>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="1"> <b>INFORME DE:</b>'.$row["nombreInforme"].'</td>
                        <td colspan="1" > <b>Categoría:</b>'.$row["categoria"].'</td>
                    </tr>                   
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="1"> <b>Fecha:</b>'.$row["fecha"].'</td>
                        <td colspan="1"> <b>Hora:</b>'.$row["hora"].'</td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="1"> <b>Nombre:</b>'.$row["nombre"].'</td>
                        <td colspan="1"> <b>Licencia:</b>'.$row["licencia"].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="1"> <b>Categoría:</b>'.$row["categoria2"].'</td>
                        <td colspan="1"> <b>Manga:</b>'.$row["manga"].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"> <b>Hora del hecho::</b>'.$row["horaHecho"].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"> <b>Descripción:</b>
                            <br>
                            <p class="justified">'.$row["descripcion"].'</p>
                            <br>  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <div class="titular-inscripcion foot">
                            <img id="footer" class="headers" src="ImagenesNoticias/'.$row_headers["timestamp"].'_'.$row_headers["footer"].'"/>
                    </div>
```

Here the css

```
    .headers{
    width:100%;
    }
    td{
    //border:1px solid black;
    text-align:left;
    height:25px;
    }
tr{
    //border:1px solid red;
}
table{
   // border:1px solid green;
    height:75%;
    width:85%;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto
}
.justified{
    text-align:justify;
}
.tabledivinscripcion{
    background:#FFF;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:0px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.foot{
    position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;
}
.pdescripcion{
    text-align: justify;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.titular-inscripcion{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
    width: 100%; /*Optional*/
    table-layout: fixed; /*Optional*/
}
```

This code attached is the final version of the pdf. To do the same with div's I tried to put div with display:table as the table tag, and div with display:table-row as the tr tag, and finally div with display:table-cell as the td tag.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share a sample of the HTML/CSS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Dompdf does work with tables built using the CSS table display types. For example, the following should display a table at 100% width with two columns. You'll notice that table-specific attributes will apply as appropriate. In the first row and a single spanning column in the second row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style>
    .table { display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
    .table-row { display: table-row; }
    .table-cell { display: table-cell; border: 1px solid black; padding: 1em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell"><b>INFORME DE:</b>dompdf</div>
      <div class="table-cell"><b>Categoría:</b>tables</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell" colspan="2"> <b>Hora del hecho:</b>9:00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What it does not support as of the current release (0.7.0 as of this post) is CSS declarations that relate to responsive design such as media queries (beyond those targeting a specific display type, e.g. `@media print`).

Instead of creating a page with multiple structural elements (tables and div tables) you should consider creating multiple stylesheets for the various display environments. You can always target dompdf in your stylesheet by surrounding the relevant CSS with `@media dompdf { ... }`.